# An equation that implies something else

Tags: complex-analysis

We suppose that $(1+|x|^2)y=(1+|y|^2)x$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$. I want to show that $x=y$ or $\overline xy=1$.

Clearly, if $x=0$ then $y=0$. Now, we suppose that $x\neq 0$ and $x\neq y$, then I want to prove that $\overline xy=1$.

We have $\dfrac yx=\dfrac{1+|y|^2}{1+|x|^2}$, but $\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{y\overline x}{|x|^2}$, so we have that $y\overline x=\dfrac{1+|y|^2}{1+|x|^2}\cdot |x|^2$

Also, $\dfrac{1+|y|^2}{1+|x|^2}\cdot |x|^2=1$ iff $|x|^2+|x|^2\cdot |y|^2=1+|x|^2$ iff $|x|\cdot |y|=1$.

So, is there an easy way to show that $|x|\cdot |y|=1$? What do you think?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, everything is trivial. Let us concentrate on the case $x, y \ne 0$. Notice

$$(1+|x|^2) y = (1+|y|^2) x \quad\iff\quad(1+|x|^2)\bar{y} = (1+|y|^2)\bar{x}$$

This implies
$$\frac{\bar{y}}{y} = \frac{(1+|x|^2)\bar{y}}{(1+|x|^2)y} = \frac{(1+|y|^2)\bar{x}}{(1+|y|^2)x} = \frac{\bar{x}}{x}$$

Let this common value be $k$, we can rewrite our original condition as:

$$\begin{align}
(1+|x|^2)y - (1+|y|^2)x = 0 \iff & (1 + kx^2) y - (1+ky^2)x = 0 \\
\iff & (x-y)(k xy - 1) = 0\\
\iff & (x-y)(\bar{x}y - 1 ) = 0\\
\iff & ( x = y ) \vee ( \bar{x}y = 1 )
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If
$$a+\frac1a = b+ \frac1b, \quad a,b >0$$
then $a=b$ or $a=1/b$.

> The function $t+\dfrac1t$ decreases on $(0,1)$ and increases on $(1,+\infty)$.

Or if you prefer more elementary methods then

> multiply both sides by $a$ and write as
>  $$(a-b)\left( a- \frac1b \right) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=r_xe^{j\alpha}$ and $y=r_ye^{j\beta}$
$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{1+{|y|}^2}{1+{|y|}^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{r_ye^{j\beta}}{r_xe^{j\alpha}}=\frac{1+{r_y}^2}{1+{r_x^2}}$$

Now since RHS is real and positive $\alpha=\beta$

Cross multiplying and simplifying 
$$r_x-r_y+r_xr_y(r_y-r_x)=0 $$
$$\Rightarrow r_x=r_y \text{ or }r_xr_y=1 $$
$$\text{In other words }r_xr_ye^{j\alpha -j\beta}=1 \text{ or } x\bar{y}=1  $$